# Add time from all log files using bash

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, logs, cat

I want to extract time from all of my `.log` files and add all of these times into a single entity. My log files are placed in nested directories.

Directory structure for my log files:

```
|-- temp-system
|   |-- bash
|   |   |-- bash-4.3-branch_update-5.patch
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|   |-- binutils
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|   |-- build-variables
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|   |-- bzip2
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|   |-- check
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|   |-- cloog
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|   |-- gettext
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |-- build.sh
|   |   `-- DONE
|-- build-system
|   |-- gcc
|   |   |-- build.log
|   |   |...
```

Snippet of my log files:

```
are/man/man1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo/texinfo-5.2/man'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo/texinfo-5.2/man'
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo/texinfo-5.2'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo/texinfo-5.2'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo/texinfo-5.2'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo/texinfo-5.2'
/tmp/panda64/temp-system/texinfo

real    1m59.973s
user    1m26.352s
sys     0m11.820s
```

Every log file has these last three lines `real`, `user` and `sys`. I want to extract all these out of my log files and add them and output in a format `HH:MM:SS`. I was trying to achieve this using `cat` and `grep` but haven't been able to get the `regex` right.

**UPDATE**

To traverse the directory, I'm using the following code:

```
list=(temp-system build-system)
for direcs in ${list[@]}; do
    case $direcs in
        temp-system )
            pushd $direcs
                _list1=(bash binutils build-variables)
                for subdirecs in ${_list1[@]}; do
                    case $subdirecs in
                        * )
                            # execute code to add the time
                            # and later add this with other
                            # time calculated from other directories
                            ;;
                    esac
                done
            popd;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I don't know the output format of `time` good enough but `grep -r --include *.log '\(real\|user\|sys\)\s\+[0-9]\+' temp-system` should give you all lines containing real, user or sys plus some spacing plus something beginning with a number.

Comment: 'add them' - do you mean a+b calculation or just putting to the end of a single sile? For calculation you definitely will need longer way to go.

Comment: @Putnik I want to do a+b calculation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that huge script to traverse the files you can just use find:

```
find /var/log -name *.log -exec ls {} \;
```

Replace the path and the 'ls' in the -exec to fit your needs.

As for grepping for the time you can do something like:

```
grep "^real\t" time.txt | awk '{ print  $NF }'
```

I cannot come up with a pretty solution to formatting it though.

Comment: And how do I add the times? Is there an easy way to do it or will I have to get my hands dirty?

Comment: I think you'll have to get your hands dirty since the output is minutes then seconds. I cannot find a nice way to do it since the output could look like `1m4.006s`. I was toying around with something like `grep "^real\t" time.txt | awk '{ print  $NF }' | sed 's/m/:/' | sed 's/.....$//'` but then you would easily miss some 0's, ie. the above would become 1:4.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a file containing times in the form `1m59.973s` (eg. the output from [Mikael Kjær's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286061/90751)), you can transform them into a single sum for [bc(1)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/bc/):

```
( cat alltimes.log | sed 's_h_*3600+_;s_m_*60+_;s_s_+_' | tr -d '\n' ; echo 0 ) | bc
```

That prints a number of seconds (including decimal places).  Then `bash` (whose arithmetic expansion doesn't handle decimals) can break it up and reformat it:

```
TOTAL=`( cat alltimes.log | sed 's_h_*3600+_;s_m_*60+_;s_s_+_' | tr -d '\n' ; echo 0 ) | bc`
INT=${TOTAL%.*}
DEC=${TOTAL#*.}
H=$((INT/3600))
M=$((INT/60%60))
S=$((INT%60))
printf %02i:%02i:%02i.%s $H $M $S $DEC
```